# Using Privacy Badger and/or Ublock on Tor

Tags: plugins, tor

I am trying to check if it is ok to use the privacy-badger or Ublock origin on Tor. I know the former was previously recommended against as it used your browsing history to build up a blocklist. However, this is no longer the case.

I can find a mention of the "approved plugins" list on the tor website but can't find that list so I don't know if either of these are on it.

Thanks,